# Boot-Repair unsuccesful

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

One of my students had an HP laptop that stopped working. The librarian thought it would be a good idea to replace the current os with Lubuntu. After trying many times the installation wasn't working. I took to the internet and was able to boot the live version with the USB. Even then, I wasn't able to access GParted or most other applications. Eventually I found out that if I tried booting in using acpi=off I was able to get in and use everything. Rebootting the laptop causes a boot error unless I have the USB in and even then I can only use the system if I click the "try lubuntu without installing" option. Now I am trying to run Boot-Repair but it doesn't seem to be working. I am very new to the system and I don't think I'm all that tech savvy so I'm asking your help. The pastebin url boot-repair gave me was http://paste.ubuntu.com/26083623/

Please send help!

P.S. I only need Lubuntu, I don't plan on duel-booting with windows or anything.

Comment: It does not look like grub bootloader fully installed, not sure then if rest of system fully installed. Did you run the suggested fixes and also comment  on 'apt --fix-broken install'? HP does not like booting in UEFI mode anything but "Windows Boot Manager" by description. If only booting Lubuntu we can change description from ubuntu to Windows but really boot Lubuntu. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 see option IV and I.

Comment: I remember having once a entry level business class HP notebook that exhibit the behavior described above but only when dual booting - it always booted Windows directly, overriding the boot priority - but with Ubuntu alone it worked as expected, installed and booted Ubuntu.